# i can't remove the margin or padding from the columns and rows of bootstrap as it looks fine

Tags: html, css

Hey i don't know what the hell with my code. I don't know where is margin and padding and my carousel and news block have margin at the top and sides while the below divs have no any padding or margin..

```css
.affix{
 z-index:2000;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.navbar{
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.hint
{
 color:#FF0000;
}
#box{
 //border:1px solid red;
 height:440px;
}
#box:hover{
 box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
 color: blue;
}
#mst_visited_product:hover{
 box-shadow: 5px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
}
#container #image #title
{
 border: 0px solid red;
 min-height: 100px;
 min-width: 400px;
 float: left;
}
#container img
{ 
 height:440px;
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
}
#clear
{
 clear : both;
}
#container
{
 min-height : 100px;
 width : 100%;
 margin : 0px;
}

#picture
{
 border : 2px solid white;
 height : 281px;
 width : 281px;
 float : left;
 margin-left : 35px;
 margin-right : 35px;
 margin-top : 35px;
}
#container #picture img
{ 
 margin:0px;
 z-index: -1;
 width:  100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}
#picture:hover
{
 border: 2px solid blue;
}
#header
{
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 200px;
}
a
{
 text-decoration: none;
}
#men_collection h2
{
 margin : 10px;
}
#women_collection h2
{
 margin : 10px;
}
#grooms_collection h2
{
 margin : 10px;
}
#brides_collection h2
{
 margin : 10px;
}
#men_collection
{
 min-width: 50px;
 float: left;
 //border: 1px solid red;
}
#women_collection
{
 float: left;
 min-width: 50px;
}
#grooms_collection
{
 min-width: 50px;
 float: left;
}
#brides_collection
{
 min-width: 50px;
 float: left;
}
#home
{
 float: left;
 width: 50px;
}
#home img
{
 height : 100%;
 width : 50px;
}

#footer
{
 border: 1px solid green;
 height: 350px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" Content="IE=edge, chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:150px;">
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
 <div class="form-group input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search.." />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
   </button>
  </span>
 </div>
</form>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
<a class="navbar-brand col-lg-3" href="#">Monaj</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">


<ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-8">
 <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> Home</span></a></li>
 <li><a href="sub_category.php?id=1">Men Collection</a></li>
 <li><a href="sub_category.php?id=2">Women Collection</a></li>
 <li><a href="sub_category.php?id=3">Grooms Collection</a></li>
 <li><a href="sub_category.php?id=4">Brides Collection</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav col-lg-1 navbar-right">
 <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> Login</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div id="main">
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-9 col-sm-9" style="min-height:100px">
<div id="container">
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="products_images/147.jpg" alt="Pashmina">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="products_images/219.jpg" alt="Woolen">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="products_images/432.jpg" alt="Silk">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="products_images/343.jpg" alt="Shawl">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-3" >
<div class="col-lg-12" id="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12 mst"><p style="text-align:center; text-shadow:4px; font-size:39px; background:grey; margin:0; padding:0;"><strong>Most Visited Products</strong></p></div>
</div>
<div id="mst_visited_product" style="height:300px;" class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div id="mst_visited_product" style="height:300px;" class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div id="mst_visited_product" style="height:300px;" class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div id="mst_visited_product" style="height:300px;" class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div id="footer" class="col-lg-12" style="height:300px;color:black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**

### strong text

**

Answer (score 1):

That's because bootstrap has it's own padding and margin styles applied when you use the col class names like col-lg, col-sm, etc

I'm sure you can manually override any padding or margin you want just by applying another class with an overriding style, probably don't have to use !important.

I found this as a kill-all padding for columns technique:

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

So now just add the .no-gutter class if you want no padding in all columns for example. Hope this helps.

Comment: I was going to actually say the exact same thing. This is a great method.

Comment: It still doesn't work. You can see that footer is fine and the above 4 boxes are fine but the portion above those boxes and below the navigation bar have some problem

Answer (score 1):

1) Place your bootstrap columns inside a .row class. The .row class has a negative margin that will "negate" the padding of 15px that is applied to the left and right of the columns classes, when spanning the full width. So it should look like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container-fluid col-lg-9 col-sm-9" style="min-height:100px">
  ...
  </div>
  ... all your other columns

</div>
```

2) The top "padding" you are seeing is actually a margin-bottom from the .navbar class. You can simply override this with:

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually bootstrap 4 applies css property line-height due to which there is a gap appears at the top and bottom of the div which seems to be padding but it is not padding its the line height which causes that issue.so if you want to remove that top and bottom space set line-height property to 1.
e.g div {line-height: 1 !important}
this will solve the issue